# Zend-framework Creating module using zf.php

Tags: zend-framework

I installed zf-tool using composer but i am unable to create module using zf.php command.

Please help me.It always show,
zf.php is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: oh, in case if you are still looking for it's answer, this problem had me for weeks, and i solved it through the path to zftool.

Answer (score 0):

In command prompt, in your project directory, try this instead of `zf.php`

```
php vendor/zendframework/zftool/zf.php
```

and after it you can put any zf command you like e.g creating a module

```
php vendor/zendframework/zftool/zf.php create module moduleName
```

Comment: Did it help, @Ayush ?